Error on Node JS npm/npx project creating with vite/react js "node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1205 throw err"
Currently i'm running node -v v22.0.0
Here I'm creating a new React Js porject. but when initiating the project with vite technology, it errors like this in the terminal.
npm create vite@latest

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1205
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\rvdas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'       
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1202:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1027:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:187:14)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v22.0.0

Also, when I try to create app using
npx create-react-app projectName

It also errors like above.
I tried clearning cache
npm cache clean --force

Didn't work.

Please try with node LTS 20.9.0v .

On macOS, I'm not able to reproduce this issue. How did you install Node.js 22 on Windows?

@Valentin now node js running version 20.12.2 which is with Long Term Support (LTS). But you can download version 22 selecting manually from drop down list. Link

@MdShorifulIslam I already had Node.js 22 on Windows. I was asking how you installed it. Today I was able to test on Windows and I reproduce your issue. I use pnpm usually and it's working properly with it. I'm not sure what's the cause of the issue but is either in create-vite or npm/cli.

it was a technical error after installing Visual Studio 2022. Appdata->roaming->npm directory was deleted somehow.
then i created it manually. then its solved.

Tried downgrading to 20.12.2 LTS, it worked

@MdShorifulIslam I have the issue when trying to invoke npm config as well and there's an issue on npm-cli GitHub

Try the fix below. Was originally posted here.
You have to copy C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm to %AppData%\Roaming\npm\node_modules temporarily.
I think this issue only occurs on:

Fresh installation of Node v22
Upgraded to Node v22 but never installed npm globally (npm i -g npm) before

The new npm script seems to only check global installation by default and will not use the version bundled in the Node installation directory.

Node.js 22.1.0 has been released and npm create vite@latest (and other commands) now work properly on Windows with this new version:
C:\Development> npm create vite@latest

> npx
> create-vite

√ Project name: ... vite-node22
√ Select a framework: » React
√ Select a variant: » TypeScript + SWC

Scaffolding project in C:\Development\vite-node22...

Done. Now run:

  cd vite-node22
  npm install
  npm run dev

